# Working with multiple event handlers on jQuery .on() method

Tags: jquery

Having multiple event handlers on a jQuery .on() method, like this:

```
$("div.test").on({

  mousemove: function(e){
    //do something
  },

  mouseenter: function(){
    //do something
  },

  mouseleave: function(){
    //do something
  }

});
```

Is it possible to call the mousemove function from outside the .on() method?

something like this:

```
function myFunction(e){
   //do something
};

$("div.test").on({

  mousemove: myFunction(e);

  mouseenter: function(){
    //do something
  },

  mouseleave: function(){
    //do something
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `(e)` from the end of `myFunction` inside the `on()` statement:

```
function myFunction(e){
  //do something
};

$("div.test").on({

  mousemove: myFunction,

  mouseenter: function(){
    //do something
  },

  mouseleave: function(){
    //do something
  }

});
```

The event (`e`) will be passed to `myFunction` implicitly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but try this:

```
function myFunction(e){
   //do something
};

$("div.test").on({

  mousemove: myFunction,

  mouseenter: function(){
    //do something
  },

  mouseleave: function(){
    //do something
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the function reference, not to call.

```
$("div.test").on({

  mousemove: myFunction,
  .
  .
  .
```